# HTTP Live Streaming with Encryption on Android 2.x

Tags: android

I'm trying to implement HTTP Live Streaming in my first Android app.  On top of that, I need to support encryption as well.

I see that some of this functionality (not sure about the encryption) is supported in Honeycomb.  Does anybody know if there are open source (or paid) libraries/frameworks available to support HTTP Live Streaming with encryption in 2.1/2.2 ?

Thanks,

Tony